# Regex in java to check for double consonant

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regex in Java to check if a string ends in double consonant.

My regex is not working.

```
\\w+[^aeiou]\\1$
```

Appreciate your help

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Be aware, that your idea does not only match double consonants, because of the `[^aeiou]` it also matches `100`, `1..` [see regex101](http://regex101.com/r/mM5tS5/1). Might be better using [something like this](http://regex101.com/r/mM5tS5/2).

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work since `\1` references a non-existent subpattern. You need to assign a [capturing group](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html). Capturing groups could be used later on in the regular expression as a backreference to what was matched in that captured group.

```
\\w+([^aeiou])\\1$
```

Based off the comment above about your regular expression not only matching double consonants, I would consider combining an intersection with negation to make sure the grouped character is an actual letter character.

```
(?i)\\w+([a-z&&[^aeiou]])\\1$
```

Comment: áÁàÀåÅâÂ are all vowels, too.

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
 # "(?i)\\w+(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z]){2}$"

 (?i)                # Case independent
 \w+ 
 (?:
      (?! [aeiou] )  # Not a vowel ahead
      [a-z]          # Consonant only
 ){2}
 $
```